# Limit the total length of the Regex

Tags: regex

Below is my regex expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:[-]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

I am trying to limit the length of the total string to 15 characters including the special character (`-`).

**For ex :** `BBB-123BBBWWRTY`

Comment: If you don't need the capturing group, you could use `^(?=.{15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: If you can provide more examples it would be helpful. We can avoid lookahead if there are fixed number of characters separated by **-**. And also mention about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be something like that:

```
^(?=.{15}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:[-]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: I understand "limiting the string to 15 characters" to mean "allowing at most 15 characters but possibly fewer", so I'd use `(?=.{1,15}§)` as the lookahead assertion.

Comment: Maybe. I supposed that strongly 15 digits, but after your comment, I started to think that it might be really length of [1-15] digits.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for a single entry, if I have multiple entries, then it is not working. Like 

For ex : BBB-123BB45,AAA-1234;EEE-9876

Here, I want to validate this whole input, where the delimiters are (; & ,).

I tried to structure the below regex expression for this

/^((?=.{1,15}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:[-]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(([;,](?=.{1,15}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:[-]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$/

Answer (score 1):

For *not more than* try a negative lookahead.

```
/^(?!.{16})[a-z\d]+-[a-z\d]+$/i
```